# Why this C program with "abort()" does not crash?

Tags: c, crash

I am trying to write a simple C program that crashes. I expect that the following one  crashes if no inputs are provided.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * arg[]){
  if (argc < 1){
    abort();

  }
}
```

I complied this program using gcc, and then ran it with ./a.out, but nothing happens, no crashes. Any idea of why? Thanks.

Comment: Because `argc` is always > 0

Comment: `argc < 1 ` is always false. `arg[0]` is the program name

Comment: @zell Usually argc is gretaer than 0. So use condition if (argc == 1){

Comment: Surely half a minute with a debugger would have answered this question?

Comment: Even if the condition became true, why do you expect it to crash? `abort` does not crash an application (unless wrongly implemented).

Comment: @MichaelWalz Fun fact: `execve("./a.out", 0, environ)` is allowed and will cause the program to be started with argc equal to zero.

Comment: @zwol *"On Linux, argv and envp can be specified as NULL.  In both cases, this has the same effect as specifying the argument as a pointer to a list containing a single  null  pointer.   Do  not  take advantage  of  this nonstandard and nonportable misfeature!  On many other UNIX systems, specifying argv as NULL will result in an error (EFAULT).  Some other UNIX systems treat the envp==NULL case the same as Linux."*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Fine, "`char *empty_argv = 0; execve("./a.out", &empty_argv, environ)` is allowed and will cause the program to be started with argc equal to zero." The _point_ of the observation remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't crashes because `argc` is argument count and when you execute the program with `./a.out` value of `argc` is `1`. so instead of checking

```
if (argc < 1){ /* 1<1 condition fails */
   abort();
}
```

check

```
if (argc == 1){
    abort();
}
```

*I expect that the following one crashes if no inputs are provided. ?* why you want it to crash by calling `abort()`, `exit(0)` is a good idea, it clean it up everything and terminate the process normally.

Comment: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2, gné ? standard never say `argc` can't be `0` !

Comment: @achal as Stargateur mentioned, operating systems using C++ are not required to do that according to the standard. However Linux and Windows do this, but you can't guarantee that some random embedded solution will do that as well.

Comment: yup I agree with @Stargateur

Answer (score 4):

It works. However whenever you're running it from *shell* as `./a.out` it will have one argument - the program name. The C standard ([C11 5.1.2.2.1p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2) says the following:

> 2. If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints:
>
>    - The value of `argc` shall be **nonnegative**. [i.e. >= 0!]
>
>    [...]
>
>    - **If** the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; **argv[0][0]** shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. [...]

I.e. the C standard allows the `argc` to be < 1, if it is exactly `0`.

Indeed,  it is possible to run a C program with *zero arguments* at least in Linux, with a little hack - by executing it from another program that calls `execv` with an empty argument list:

abort.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * arg[]){
    printf("argc is %d\n", argc);
    if (argc < 1){
       abort();
    }
}
```

runner.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char *args[] = { NULL };
    execv("./abort", args);
}
```

Then:

```
% gcc abort.c -o abort
% gcc runner.c -o runner
```

Now if you run `abort` directly, you'll get:

```
% ./abort
argc is 1
```

however, with `runner`:

```
./runner 
argc is 0
Aborted (core dumped)
```